# Why is axios returning a different responseURL than the request url?

Tags: react-native, axios

I am making an Axios GET request from my React Native app to my locally served backend.

The response "`config`" object shows a "`baseURL`" of "`http://192.168.1.68:8080/api`" and a "`url`" of "`inventory?status=ALL&barcode=127035838`".

The response "request" object shows a "`_url`" of "`http://192.168.1.68:8080/api/inventory?status=ALL&barcode=127035838`".

However! the response "responseURL" attribute shows a value of "`http://192.168.1.68:8080/api/inventory?status=ALL&barcode=127035838%1D`".

The request from the app is not finding the barcode, returning 204. Making the same request from Postman, I am able to find the barcode with a 200 status. This makes me believe the issue is not on the backend. I switched from Axios to fetch and found the same result.

It is my guess the additional "`%1D`" on the end of the barcode is the cause of frustration. Why is the rsponseURL different from the request url. Why is axios adding "`1%D`", and how can I make it stop? Is there something else going on?

My solution:

```
let uriSN = serialNumber;
uriSN = encodeURIComponent(serialNumber);
uriSN = uriSN.replace('%1D', '');
```

Encoding the barcode and then stripping it of the "`1%D`" solves the issue. I do not know if it is the best or complete solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%1D` is the url-encoded hex for `29` which is an ASCII control character called the "group seperator" so your serialNumber might have this character which is being parsed accordingly (by design) through the `encodeURIComponent` function. This is known as "GIGO" (garbage in garbage out).